# krb5ccame environment variable under wsgi and django

Tags: django, environment-variables, wsgi

i'm trying to set up a webauth'd webpage so that i may call remctl through it. the website is django based running on apache with wsgi.

afaiu, i have a token cache that is supplied to me as part of the environment variable KRB5CCNAME for the page load. however, i think wsgi is hiding the variable from me as i cannot see it when i do a `os.environ`. i've read somewhere that wsgi does not expose all environment variables to the application. where could this be hidden?

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Where is KRB5CCNAME being set?

If it is being set by an Apache module, then it is likely in the per request WSGI environ dictionary and not os.environ. To get access to the per request variables, from memory, you access in Django request.META.

If that doesn't help, please supply additional information by editing your original question and adding it at the end.